# ListView doesn't show my items from Itemsource

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I added items to my ListView and those elements are in there. I know that because I can click only the first two lines in my ListView and I added 2 Elements.

```
<ListView x:Name="userListview"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="40,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="User Informationen">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="User" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

and my VB.Net Code:

```vb
users = New ObservableCollection(Of UserInformation)()

        For i = 0 To globalUserList.Count - 1
            users.Add(New UserInformation() With {
                      .Username = globalUserList(i).ToString,
                      .Email = globalUserList(i + 1).ToString})
            i = i + 1
        Next

        userListview.ItemsSource = users
```

Expected result should be that those items are visible and readable.

Comment: Take a look at the Output Window in Visual Studio. You'll certainly see some data binding error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding on the property `Name`, which doesn't seem to exist.

It looks like it should be:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="User" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Username}"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this. There was a mistake in the name

```
<ListView x:Name="userListview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="40,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="User Informationen">
            <GridViewColumn Header="User" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Username}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```